# Undefined control sequence Error with moderncv+Hebrew

Tags: errors, babel, moderncv, optional-arguments

I would like to use [`modernv`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) to create a right-to-left CV document in Hebrew. I have downloaded and installed [`culmus-latex`](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/), and Hebrew+English LaTex documents compile without a problem.

I took `template.tex`, the moderncv boilerplate file, and added the Hebrew packages:

```tex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{culmus}
```

And changed the `documentclass` from:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
```

To:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english,hebrew]{moderncv}
```

I got the following error:

```
...
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/rlbabel.def
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \thesection 

l.174 }

? 
! Emergency stop.
<argument> \thesection 

l.174 }

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on template.log.
```

More info:

- I'm working on Linux Mint with standard `texlive` packages.
- The original moderncv file and the Hebrew file compile well (separately).
- All documents are encoded in [`Windows-1255`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255).
- I've uploaded the [full tex files, log files and error message](https://gist.github.com/3456151) to gist:github.

**Addendum:**

When the `inputenc` end `babel` lines are commented out:

```tex
%\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{babel}
```

The document compiles, with erroneous Hebrew encoding:

[image]

To conclude,

> [Uh, so, uh, anything you can do to, uh, to help, would be... very... helpful...](http://www.montypython.net/grailmm3.php)

Comment: Have you tried using `unicode` (utf8) encoding? `moderncv` does some hyperref setup in unicode by default, which might conflict with your encoding (just a wild guess)...

Comment: @Xavier Yes, it's unicode UTF8.

Comment: If your file is encoded in `utf8`, you need to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and remove the `\inputencoding{latin9}` and `\inputencoding{cp1255}` from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moderncv` works best with `unicode` encoding for "exotic" characters, due to some internal `hyperref` setup.

Therefore, you should encode your file in `utf8` and use

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

if you are compiling with pdfLaTeX (or nothing if you are compiling with Xe- or LuaLaTeX) and remove the `\inputencoding{latin9}` and `\inputencoding{cp1255}` from your code.