# Babel hebrew and koma-script letter

Tags: koma-script, babel, hebrew

When I try to use `babel` `hebrew` together with the KOMA-Script letter class there is a sequence of errors. After looking at the file `hebrew.ldf`, I think the reason is that `babel` `hebrew` checks for a list of document classes like `article` or `letter` in order to find out whether commands like `\thesection` should be redefined. I also found this explanation mentioned on the internet, e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/_79cjuF_6m0 (in German).

I think this is the same problem as reported in [Undefined control sequence Error with moderncv+Hebrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68674/undefined-control-sequence-error-with-moderncvhebrew).

For classes like `scrartcl` there seems to be the easy solution to define these variables to be empty. However in the case of `scrlttr2` these would be a lot of variables. So I am looking for a solution which does not include defining all these variables and preferably also does not include changing the `babel` `hebrew` files.

My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew, english]{babel}
\usepackage{culmus}

\setkomavar{subject}{\foreinglanguage{hebrew}{שלום}}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Example Person}
\opening{Dear Example,}
\ldots
\closing{Best regards,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

All the errors are of the type "Undefined control sequence", like e.g.

> ```
> ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
>
> --- TeX said ---
> <argument> \thesection 
>
> l.174 }
> ```

Comment: Well one can fool rlbabel.def to think the document is a letter by using `\makeatletter\@namedef{ver@letter.cls}{}\makeatother` but then you get other errors (and unwanted changes). Imho the `.ldf` is simply unusable with newer classes, it would need a complete rewrite.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your suggestion and as expected it resulted in new errors. Do you think that there is a chance that a complete rewrite will happen?

Comment: I have doubts. Imho xelatex or lualatex along with polyglossia is the more promising route. But I don't know much about hebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use class `scrartcl` together with package `scrletter`. So instead of telling `hebrew.ldf` that class `letter` has been loaded (see Ulrike's comment to the question) you could fake loading `article` class. Nevertheless there will still be an error message, because `scrletter` sets a label `\label{\thisletter.lastpage}` inside `\end{letter}`. This results in

```
\newlabel{\@@number {1}.lastpage}{{\beginL \@@number {1}\endL }{\@@number {1}}
```

in the `aux` file. The `\beginL` here results in an error message. I do not known whether or not `\label` is a general problem using `babel-hebrew` but you can use a simple patch to remove the last page feature if you do not need it.

With:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\makeatletter\@namedef{ver@article.cls}{0000/00/00}\makeatother
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\usepackage{culmus}

\setkomavar{subject}{\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{שלום}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% remove label from \endletter
\xpatchcmd{\endletter}{\label{\thisletter.lastpage}}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Example Person}
\opening{Dear Example,}
\ldots
\closing{Best regards,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

I don't know whether or not this is the expected result. And I do not know whether or not this hack can be used for real Hebrew letters.

Indeed best would be to have a better `babel-hebrew`.