# KOMA-script vs. memoir for non-English and multi-lingual documents

Tags: memoir, koma-script, languages, bidi

There have been several posts in this forum over the years asking for a comparison between `KOMA-Script` and `memoir`, but none of them - to the best of my knowledge - touched on the aspects of non-English and of multi-lingual documents.

So I'd like to know:

1. Given that the underlying engine/format is `luatex`/`lualatex`, how do `KOMA-script` and `memoir` compare w.r.t. non-English and multi-lingual documents I'm particularly interested in documents containing a combination of some subset of the following languages:

   - English
   - French
   - German
   - Greek
   - Hebrew
   - Japanese
2. Do `KOMA-Script` and `memoir` work well with the following programs:

   - `biblatex` + `biber`
   - `glossaries` + `xindy`
   - `imakeidx` + `xindy`

Comment: It reaaly doesn't matter what you choose w.r.t language

Comment: My experience is that Hebrew does not work well with `luatex` (`luabidi` is broken badly) . You are better off using `xelatex`.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Do both `KOMA-Script` and `memoir` work well with 1. `biblatex`+`biber`, 2. `glossaries`+`xindy`, 3. `imakeidx`+`xindy`?

Comment: As far as i know, Yes. Why shouldn't they?

Comment: @Johannes_B: In the past `memoir` didn't use to work with `imakeidx`.

Comment: @EvanAad People either use KOMA-script OR memoir. Users of both are probably rare. And of such users you are searching some, who write in Japanese, German and French!? *Why don't you draft two examples yourself?* Test it! It will take some hours, no more. And if you have a specific question, then please ask. You'll be welcome.

Comment: @KeksDose: Many people write in at least two languages. Even those who write in a single langue often use multi-lingual sources in their bibliography. And even those who write in a single language might still be able to answer my 2nd question. No one is forced to answer at all.

Comment: @KeksDose: BTW the popular CS textbook 'Lambda-Calculus and Combinators: An Introduction', 2nd ed. by Hindley and Seldin (CUP 2008) has bibliographic references in English, Russian and Japanese.

Comment: @EvanAad Yes, I'm writing english texts as well as german texts, always with a KOMA-script class, but using pdfTeX. Of course KOMA-script works with biblatex, glossary-packages and xindy. Maybe your question is to broad.

Comment: In addition to @DavidPurton's comment: In my experience Hebrew also does not work well with `pdfLaTeX`, see e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281801/babel-hebrew-and-koma-script-letter).